# Index, Match and Address functions in a formula but how do incorporate a certain condition to extract only certain data?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

My Workbook has three sheets: "Wire Sheet", "Paste Data" sheet and "Wire instructions"

I need the "Wire sheet to dynamically populate with the data from the other two sheets based on certain conditions, i.e. date and data from that date.

I am using the index, match address functions to find the names from the "paste data" tab based on a specific but I can't figure out how to put a condition in there to only return names that are "buys"...

Here are my formulas:

This is just to find the cell:

S17= =MAX(IF('Paste Data'!B:B = 'Wire Sheet'!K2, ROW('Paste Data'!B:B) - ROW(INDEX('Paste Data'!B:B,1,1))+1))

S18= =ADDRESS(MATCH(K2,'Paste Data'!B:B,0),2,3,1,"Paste Data")&":"&ADDRESS(S17,5,3,1)

S19= =INDEX(S18,1)

here is the formula i am using to return the data:
=IF(INDEX(INDIRECT(S19),1,4)=0,"",INDEX(INDIRECT(S19),1,4))

Example on how spreadsheet works:

Currently: if you place a specific date in cell K2 on the "wire sheet", the boxes (cells A18:O67) populate with the data from the other two sheets based on that specific date. The data coded "Sell" is being populated in the boxes on the wire sheet, but should not be.. here is an example:

For example: If you place the date 7/13/2018 in K2 cell, the cell B57 is populated with letters SCR, which shouldn't be the case, as if you go to the "paste data" sheet, this is a "sell".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FQi1.png)

Then if you place the date 7/16/2018 in K2 Cell -- the cell B18 is doing the same thing, its populated with WQ when it shouldn't be, as it is a "sell", on the "paste Data" sheet. I would like it to just skip over this row of data and go and find the next row that is coded "buy"..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUfxC.png)

I just want to place the data that are "buys", on the wire sheet. All the sells should be passed over. I am not sure how else to explain this, which might be part of the issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Vxc.png)

Thanks in advance.

https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZNzcB7ZpIigcTAabUz2vpPaXQ4nSVUfdc2X

Comment: Many people that would help do not download excel files; instead, post a screenshot of a useful part(s) of your sheet for us to easily look at

Comment: Either put your code or formula into the post so we can review.

Comment: please read [mcve].  you need to provide a simpler example and output the acheives what you want.  asking us to parse all that information is too broad.  Keep it simple.

Comment: Sorry I am trying to be as precise as possible. I am trying to upload some screen shots, but for some reason am not able too.

Comment: Make sure that you've saved them somewhere first - it will not upload directly from the clipboard

Comment: OK working on uploading some images. thanks again everyone.

Comment: I uploaded some images and added the formulas I am using in the description. hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+-----[editRevision2]----+

My way :

```
Y5       =COUNTIF('Paste Data'!B:B,'Wire Sheet'!K2)

Z6       =IF((ROW(Z6)-5)<=Y$5,ROW(Z6)-5,"")
AA6       =INDEX('Paste Data'!F:F,MATCH('Wire Sheet'!$K$2,'Paste Data'!B:B,0)+'Wire Sheet'!Z6-1,1)
AB6       =IF(AA6="Buy",AB5+1,AB5)
AC6       =IF(AA6="Buy",INDEX('Paste Data'!E:E,MATCH('Wire Sheet'!$K$2,'Paste Data'!B:B,0)+'Wire Sheet'!Z6-1),"")
AD6       =IF(AA6="Buy",INDEX('Paste Data'!K:K,MATCH('Wire Sheet'!$K$2,'Paste Data'!B:B,0)+'Wire Sheet'!Z6-1),"")
```

select Z6:AD6 and extend to D15, then

```
B18       =IFERROR(INDEX($AC:$AC,MATCH(A18,$AB:$AB,0)),"")
E19       =IFERROR(INDEX($AD:$AD,MATCH(A18,$AB:$AB,0)),"")
```

copy B18 to J18, B31, J31 ...
and copy E20 to J20, B33, J33 ...

+-----[ProviousEdit]----+

Make

```
B18   =if(SUMIFS('Paste Data'!$K:$K,'Paste Data'!$E:$E,IF(INDEX(INDIRECT(S19),1,4)=0,"",INDEX(INDIRECT(S19),1,4)),'Paste Data'!$B:$B,$K$2,'Paste Data'!$F:$F,"Buy")=0,"",IF(INDEX(INDIRECT(S19),1,4)=0,"",INDEX(INDIRECT(S19),1,4)))
```

and adjust the `INDEX(INDIRECT(S19),1,4)` accordingly for J18,B31,J31 ...

Hope that solves.. (:

Comment: This wont work because the "buy" condition is in another column.. So I think I have to add this condition at another level, which is what I can not figure out. I think am may be over thinking my logic here. Thanks again!

Comment: We are getting somewhere! But its not working, if the first row is a sell.. let me see If i can figure this out.

Comment: you mean, if the last row = buy, all WQ,EL,,EM ... should be displayed, and if the last row = sell, output <blank> right?

Comment: Your solution definitely works, but I was trying to make it so, the cell B18 will populate with the first "buy" in the array.. So because the table/array, the first row is a sell, I want the formula to skip over that and move onto the next one, check to see if it is a "buy" and if so then return the name.. Is that possible?! Maybe what I am trying to do isnt possible?

Comment: count how many match > generate new list > anchor both output to boxnumber @ B18.

Comment: I tried this and it actually didnt work for me. Thanks for trying! Really appreciate the time you took out to help me out.

Comment: @ap5 can you share what you get? I tried this using your uploaded file, here is the [result](https://utpmy-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/mohammad_g03606_utp_edu_my/EYol8xCHFRBLmoHEqsj7UDYB7PLbkkotLWhrcAIgBt46WQ?e=XKgYvS). [  Note : all proposed [editRevision2] solution formulas are to be applied at "Wire Sheet".

Comment: Yes your spreadsheet works great! Let me see where I went wrong.

Comment: updated post : noticed that I've mistakenly share the formula for E20 instead of the supposedly E19. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you so much, for all your help! This totally worked :)

Comment: Nice work on the "manual" address generation algorithm you'd shared. It is enlightening. | You're welcome. (: